# SPARQL list literals of selected OWL Datatype

Tags: sparql, owl

How to list all literals of only selected OWL datatype (here :VisibilityKind) in SPARQL? The OWL datatype definition of VisibilityKind is:

```
DatatypeDefinition( :VisibilityKind 
    DataOneOf( "public"^^xsd:string "private"^^xsd:string "package"^^xsd:string ) 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

With SPARQL, you can get all the literals that have a certain datatype IRI. For instance, assuming you have data with literals such as `"public"^^:VisibilityKind`, you can write:

```
SELECT ?literal WHERE {
    ?s ?p ?literal .
    FILTER (datatype(?literal) = :VisibilityKind)
}
```

But this is certainly not what you want because you probably do not have literals with this datatype IRI. What you would probably like is something that could roughly be formulated as:

```
SELECT ?literal WHERE {
    ?s ?p ?literal .
    FILTER (isInDatatype(?literal,:VisibilityKind))
}
```

where `isInDatatype` checks if the value associated with `?o` belongs to the value space of `:VisibilityKind`. However, such function does not exist in standard SPARQL 1.1. Moreover, even if it existed, it would require the query engine to understand the semantics of OWL 2 and do reasoning. So you would need a SPARQL engine that implements the [OWL 2 DL entailment regime](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-entailment/#OWLDSEntRegime) and you'd have to hack a bit the query to get what you want:

```
SELECT ?literal WHERE {
    ?s ?p ?literal .
    [] a :VisibilityKind;
       :owl:sameAs ?literal;
    FILTER (isLiteral(?literal))
}
```

If you want to find implementations of SPARQL 1.1 Entailment regimes, you could take a look at the [implementation reports](https://www.w3.org/2009/sparql/implementations/#sparql11-entailment) collected by the SPARQL working group.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer. I am having a trouble because I am using SPARQL 1.1 (I'm working with Protege tool). Therfore I cannot even check your second and thrid query.

Comment: In your query how ?literal is iniciated?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, I wrote `?o` instead of `?literal` but I just edited it to correct the error.

Comment: If that's really the datatype and reasoning as well as custom datatypes are not supported, then you can use a simple SPARQL query with `FILTER(?literal IN ("public"^^xsd:string, "private"^^xsd:string, "package"^^xsd:string))`

Comment: In Protege you have to use the *Snap SPARQL plugin* if you need reasoning support.

Answer (score 0):

To answer directly, you need to search for all values in the `owl:oneOf` list:

```
SELECT ?resource ?value
WHERE {
   :VisibilityKind owl:equivalentClass / owl:oneOf / ( rdf:rest*/rdf:first ) ?value .
   ?resource ?prop ?value .
}
```

However, there is a caveat - other properties could have the value "public" "private" or "package".  To ensure that you're getting only the values of `:VisibilityKind`, define that datatype as a range of properties that use the datatype:

```
{ :someProp rdfs:domain :VisibilityKind }
```

Then use the following query to get all properties that define `:VisibilityKind` in the range:

```
SELECT ?resource ?value
WHERE {
   ?prop rdfs:range :VisibilityKind .
   ?resource ?prop ?value
}
```

Comment: According to https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-mapping-to-rdf/, the DatatypeDefinition axiom is represented as `T(DT) owl:equivalentClass T(DR) .` This means the left hand side (DT) will be `:VisibilityKind`and the data range (DR) which in fact is the DataOneOf by `_:x rdf:type rdfs:Datatype .
_:x owl:oneOf T(SEQ lt1 ... ltn) .` Are you sure that your query will match that? I would think that `?o` would be the blank node which has another edge via the predicate `owl:oneOf` to the list of values. But maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: It is indeed as @AKSW said, the proposed querry does not match it.

Comment: Not sure if the first or the second query was being referred to.  I edited the first to include the `owl:equivalentClass` definition.

Comment: @Annabelle: Just a question to clarify what you really want: Do you want to have a) all values specified by the datatype or b) all values in the knowledge base that belong to the datatype (which in fact is a subset of a))?

Comment: I am interested only in B (current knowledge about the datatype). Additionally I know that it is a kind of enumeration (DataOneOf) plus I know that this datatype is named (as e.g. :VisibilityKind). Plus currently I am limited to SPARQL 1.1 (I will try to update but I am not sure if it will be possible due to the list of dependences)

Comment: SPARQL 1.1 is the latest version.

Comment: Then answer given by @Antoine Zimmermann should work, but I cannot run it